# Detect a new line in android text view

Tags: java, android, text

I am trying to create my first Android application in which it will help me do some outlining.

Quite simply I am trying to write some sort of detection that when a line starts with a hyphen, the next time there is a new line a hyphen will be placed in front of that new line.

I am looking for any pointers or directions for where I should be looking, as this is my first app.

Or in another sense what would be the best way to detect text being typed and change the `EditText` based on it.

Comment: Have you completed the [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the text watcher class of android which can be attached to a event.

```
EditText mPasswordLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_length);
mPasswordLength.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
    }
});
```

The method you can use to edit the text is onTextChanged. More detailed description about when and why these events are fired is explained in this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476848/android-textwatcher-aftertextchanged-vs-textwatcher-ontextchanged). Read the answer with max up votes.

Answer (score 2):

Since OnKeyListener does not work for Soft keyboard, I recommend using the TextWatcher.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    if( -1 != charSequence.toString().indexOf("\n") ){
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

When you want to replace this sequence by some other string, try this:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    int i = editable.toString().indexOf("\n");
    if ( i != -1 ) {
        editable.replace(i, i+1, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an `OnKeyListener` for the `EditText`, then in the listener's `onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` method, see if it is the `event` is `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and the `keyCode` is for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`, if so then append a '-' to the end of the edittext.