# How can I intercept text before it is inserted into a TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

In Android, I am writing an app where the user enters text into an `EditText` view, and I would like to intercept that text before the system actually inserts it into the view, so that I can first wrap it in a `SpannableText` and do some decoration.

Is there any way to do this, or do I need to wait until the text is inserted, and then replace it in the `afterTextChanged` method (which seems like a waste of processing!)

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to implement a syntax highlighting or something different?

Comment: Kind of - I want to highlight some words, based on some conditions, then turn off the highlight after a short time.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that this can be achieved using [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). I hope this helps you even though I can't provide any examples. You can set a `TextWatcher` to your EditText via `mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use the TextWatcher class :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Good luck !

Comment: I know the TextWatcher can detect an insertion, but I don't see any way to get it to actually replace anything.

Comment: @VictorGrazi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476848/android-textwatcher-aftertextchanged-vs-textwatcher-ontextchanged read both answers there

Comment: Those answers don't seem to help - seems like TextWatcher needs a hook for you to decorate text before it is actually inserted into the EditText component