# EditText proper validation

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext

I would like to have EditText with some simple validation. I would like it to gain decimal numbers in format 8 symbols before comma and 2 symbols after comma.

I've found some examples here, but I can't figure out why are they not working for me. I was trying to set InputFilter, but I can't create a valid regex.

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(final int digitsBeforeZero,
            final int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern = Pattern.compile("place for my regex");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(final CharSequence source, final int start,
            final int end, final Spanned dest, final int dstart,
            final int dend) {

        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(dest);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `TextWatcher` could be an alternative for you.
See:

[Android TextWatcher.afterTextChanged vs TextWatcher.onTextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476848/android-textwatcher-aftertextchanged-vs-textwatcher-ontextchanged)

http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/text/TextWatcher.java.html

This way you don't have to use regex and you can check the text before it's display better.