# BeforeTextChanged event doesn't return the text about to be entered in custom Entry Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.entry

I've a custom Entry Renderer in Android and I've implemented BeforeTextChanged event so that I get the text which is gonna be entered, but it doesn't return that text.

I've implemented in two different ways:

- First implementing ITextWatcher by the class and then overriding the mentioned event (helping this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263021/5941852)):

  ```
  void ITextWatcher.BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
  {

      var test1 = new string(s?.ToArray());
      var test2 = Control?.Text;

      SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(s);
      BackgroundColorSpan backgroundSpan = new     BackgroundColorSpan(Color.Blue);
      spannableString.SetSpan(backgroundSpan, start, start + count, 
      SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
      var test3 = spannableString;

  }
  ```
- Second way:

  ```
  Control.BeforeTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
  {

      var test1 = new string(args?.Text.ToArray());
      var entry = sender as EditText;
      var test2 = entry?.Text;
      var test3 = Control?.Text; 

  };
  ```

But none of them will return the text that is about to be entered.
What I want is to access that text and only in some circumstances allowing it to be inserted.
I don't wanna use Behavior as it doesn't suit my need.

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First way, `ITextWatcher`:

```
 class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public MyEntryRenderer() : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
                Control.AddTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
            }
        }
    }
    class MyTextWatcher :Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
    {

        public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "afterTextChanged ---->" + s);

        }

        public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "beforeTextChanged ----> s=" + s + "----start=" + start
          + "----after=" + after + "----count" + count);
        }


        public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "onTextChanged ---->s=" + s + "----start=" + start
+ "----before=" + before + "----count" + count);
        }
    }
```

it works well.

Second way, `Control.BeforeTextChanged`, it also works well.

> it doesn't return that text

The methods you provided in your question, they are all work well in my phone. Please show more codes, so I can help you find where is wrong.

Comment: It didn't work too. Suppose we wanna enter the first character (say "a") into the entry, so BeforeTextChanged must return "a". But it returns an empty value i.e "".

Comment: Hey wait, maybe I'm making a mistake. Can we expect that BeforeTextChanged returns the very text that is gonna be entered???

Comment: Hi, if there is "a" in your entry, and you enter "b", BeforeTextChanged  will return "a". OnTextChanged and AfterTextChanged will return "ab". By `returns the very text`, what do you mean?

Comment: What I meant by that is suppose you're gonna enter the char "a" as the first character in the entry. I wanted to get this "a" in BeforeTextChanged event and prevent it from being inserted in the entry. Though I think I was wrong and this event won't give us that!

Comment: Yes, you are right, `BeforeTextChanged` won't return "a", because it doesn't belong to `BeforeTextChanged` event. It belongs to `OnTextChanged` and `AfterTextChanged` events. You need make a demo to test these event.