# How to add a textview when typing in another textview?

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener

I have a group of edittext, the number of the edittext depend on how many steps user will type in.

What I want to implement is to show one edittext at initial, then when user type in the current edittext, it will add a new blank edittext below.
How should I implement this listener?

I think about using textwatcher, it will listen on every character it changed, but I only need to listen to the first character.

Comment: how do you type in a textView ?? are you talking abt edittext ?

Comment: yes it's edittext

Answer (score 0):

How about an EditText dynamically if the charSequence lenght correspond to your value ?

There you would use a textWatcher on your first Edit

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
     if ((after == 1) && (count== 0) && start == 0))
        //Implement a new EditText dynamically

}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
```

}

As explained here  ; [Differences between TextWatcher 's onTextChanged, beforeTextChanged and afterTextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278382/differences-between-textwatcher-s-ontextchanged-beforetextchanged-and-aftertex)

start is the start index of the text

count is the length of the text before modification

after is the length of the modified text

Comment: Then when I delete the text in edittext, when there is only one char left, it will add a new EditText again.

Comment: Then use the beforeTextChanged function the int after is the futur lenght of the string whereas start is the previous lenght. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     if(s.length == 0){
       // This means user has erased all the text from the edittext.
       // For this instance you have to remove the added edittext.
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      if(s.length == 0){
        // It means your this was your initial input before changing text
        // add another edit text at this moment.
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```