# How do I update a progress bar using text watcher for multiple fields in a form?

Tags: java, android

I have a bunch of fields: first name, last name, e-mail, password and I need to update the progress bar every time they have valid entries in them. So e.g. if email address and last name are filled the `ProgressBar` should be 50% full. The user can enter the fields in any order but the `ProgressBar` should always show what the updated progress level is. I am using `addTextChangeListener(Text Watcher)`.

```
firstName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int length = s.toString().trim().length();
            if (length > 0) {
                registrationProgress.setProgress(registrationProgress.getProgress() + 25);
            } else {
                registrationProgress.setProgress(registrationProgress.getProgress() - 25);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

When I run the above, I get the `ProgressBar` to keep on adding 25 with every text entry instead of when the entire field is populated and the user as tapped out of that field. What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> When I run the above, I get the progress bar to keep on adding 25 with every text entry [...] What am I doing wrong?

[Differences between TextWatcher's onTextChanged, beforeTextChanged and afterTextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278382/differences-between-textwatcher-s-ontextchanged-beforetextchanged-and-aftertex) will help you to understand why your app is behaving that way.

> what should I do?

You can override `afterTextChanged()` instead of `onTextChanged()` because you're not interested in how often the user typed a letter (or hit the backspace key). In `afterTextChanged()`, you evaluate the length of the `String` which has been entered in the `EditText` so far.

In order to keep track of the progress, I'd like to introduce a

```
private SparseBooleanArray isTextComplete = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

as well as a method

```
private void checkProgress(){
    int progress = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <  isTextComplete.size(); i++){
        if(isTextComplete.valueAt(i)){
            progress++;
        }
    }
    registrationProgress.setProgress(progress * 25);
}
```

In `afterTextChanged()`, you can update the `SparseBooleanArray` and call `checkProgress()`:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int len = etMail.getText().toString().length();
    if(len > 0){
        isTextComplete.put(etMail.getId(), true);
    }
    else{
        isTextComplete.put(etMail.getId(), false);
    }
    checkProgress();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the above, I get the progress bar to keep on adding 25 with every text

This is because you're using the following code (please read the comment):

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    int length = s.toString().trim().length();

    // if string not empty, keep adding the progress with 25
    if (length > 0) {
        registrationProgress.setProgress(registrationProgress.getProgress() + 25);
    } 
    // subtract 25 each time string empty.
    else {
        registrationProgress.setProgress(registrationProgress.getProgress() - 25);
    }

}
```

you can see that you're always adding 25 if there is a non empty string or subtracting 25 if no non empty string found.

To solve the problem, you need to keep tracking for each text change in  first name, last name, e-mail, password. You can use HashMap combined with Enum. Something like this:

```
public YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ...

   // this is the list of entry
   private enum Entry {
     FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD
   }

   // keep tracking the entry where Boolean is the value if entry already inserted
   private HashMap<Entry, Boolean> mMapEntries = new HashMap<>();

   private void checkAndValidateEntries() {
     // initialize the entry as not inserted yet
     mMapEntries.put(FIRST_NAME, false);
     mMapEntries.put(LAST_NAME, false);
     mMapEntries.put(EMAIL, false);
     mMapEntries.put(PASSWORD, false);


     // then handle the entry view
     // here the example only for firstname
     firstName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        ...

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int length = s.toString().trim().length();
            if (length > 0) {
               boolean isInserted = mMapEntries.get(FIRST_NAME);
               // do changes if entry not yet inserted before.
               if(isInserted == false) {
                  // progress percentage per entry
                  int percentage = 100 / mMapEntries.size();

                  // add the progress
                  int progress = registrationProgress.getProgress() + percentage;
                  registrationProgress.setProgress(progress);

                  // we now have inserted the value, so mark it.
                  mMapEntries.put(FIRST_NAME, true);
               }
            } else {
               boolean isInserted = mMapEntries.get(FIRST_NAME);
               // Do changes if entry already inserted before.
               if(isInserted == true) {
                  int percentage = 100 / mMapEntries.size();

                  // subtract the progress.
                  int progress = registrationProgress.getProgress() - percentage;
                 registrationProgress.setProgress(progress);

                 // entry is removed, mark as not inserted yet
                 mMapEntries.put(FIRST_NAME, false);
               }
            }

        }

        ...
     });


     // handle the last name, e-mail, password
     ...
   }

}
```

The above code will only increase the progress value if an entry progress isn't added to the progress before and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding 25 each time that the field text is changing. For example, if you write "Hello", you have five letters so `onTextChanged` will be triggered 5 times.

A possible workarrond is to create flags for each field, just a `boolean` to indicate if the field is filled or not. Then you check how many flags are set to "filled" and set the `ProgressBar` accordingly.

Hope it helps.