# How can I get new entered value on EditText with TextWatcher

Tags: android, textview, android-textwatcher

I can get the old value. But I do not have a solution to get a new entered 
value.

**In fact**, I want to separate the old value from the new value.
For example: If `oldText=hello` and new entered EditText value equal to (`hello w` or `w hello`), I want `newText=w`.

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {


    private String oldText = "";
    private String newText = "";

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        this.oldText = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `start` and`count` parameters in the `onTextChanged` method, you can calculate and get the new typed value.

[onTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int))

> This method is called to notify you that, within `s`, the `count`
>   characters beginning at `start` have just replaced old text that had
>   length `before`. It is an error to attempt to make changes to `s` from
>   this callback.

So you can:

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private String newTypedString = "";

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        newTypedString = s.subSequence(start, start + count).toString().trim();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {


    private String oldText = "";
    private String newText = "";

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        this.oldText = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        newText = s.toString().replace(oldText, "").trim();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

}
```

Info about text watcher:
[Differences between TextWatcher 's onTextChanged, beforeTextChanged and afterTextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278382/differences-between-textwatcher-s-ontextchanged-beforetextchanged-and-aftertex)