# How to handle Number Format Exception in edittext OntextChanged

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have edit text in my app to manipulate product quantity, but the issue if I will change the quantity , on that time getting NPE. to change the quantity in edit text I need to remove existing and need to add a new one, please check following code

```
viewHolder.edt_product_qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


                    quantity_count= Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString());


                    buyNowList(user_id,"UserCart",0,stList.get(position).getCartList1().getId(),stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdSku(),stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdId(),quantity_count,0,qty_status,stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdPrice());

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Please share your code complete and your error  , is this a adapter ?

Comment: yes this is adapter..and i am using edittext value to call my api..so to change quantity it is getting null and giving NPE

Comment: Share your adapter code complete!!!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/t6erHe4x

Comment: Why don't you catch NumberFormatException of Integer.parseInt? Your app will crash if there will be no number in edt_product_qty (e. g. when user delete all the text).

Comment: So, if the error is in the adapter, why do you think it is `onTextChanged` error? By the way, in most cases `afterTextChanged` is used. And what are the values of variables there? In what line does the error raise?

Comment: @KirylTkach yes getting numberformat exception..hope you understand the issue..can you give solution

Comment: @chris you can user digits property of edit text to restrict input of the user to only numbers like this, digits='0123456789' then user can not input alphabets.

Comment: post the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove everything on your editText, editText will return an empty string. Hence you will get `NPE` and also `Number Format Exception`.

You can handle like this:

```
if(!viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString().equals("")){
   quantity_count= Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString()); 
   buyNowList(user_id,"UserCart",0,stList.get(position).getCartList1().getId(),stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdSku(),stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdId(),quantity_count,0,qty_status,stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdPrice());
}
```

**To compare initial value with current value**

First you need to assign a variable as initial value  in `beforeTextChanged`.

```
initalValue =viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString();
```

Then in `onTextChanged`:

```
if(!viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString().equals("")){
    quantity_count = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString()); // 
}if(initalValue>quantity_count)
{
    // code
}else
{
    //code
}
```

Have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20278708/5156075

Comment: where should i add this condition ? inside ontextchanged or aftertextchanged?

Comment: `onTextCanged`.

Comment: getting error  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

quantity_count= Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString());

on this line

Comment: is there any way i can check, updated value greater than existing one..for example..if i change from 2 to 5 so 5 is bigger vice versa

Comment: when you want to compare? After one of the button is clicked?

Comment: when i change quantity,, like existing is 5 then i change it to 2,, so i need to compare it is higher or lesser than existing one...got it??

Comment: initial value and quantity_count both will have same value if we do that way

Comment: store initial value in `beforeTextChanged`

Comment: hi i am getting one more issue

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: this edittext is product quantity, now i have two button plus and minus beside edittext..on this button i am calling same buyNow method..now if user click on plus and minus and manipulate with quantity of edittext,,it is calling buyNow method twice.. one for button and one which we have used in edittext..getting my point?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UuJGj5wa check this one..while i call button click listener,,i am calling buynow method, so on that time method inside edittext listener is also calling..that is the issue..

Comment: where is buyNow method ? You mean buyNowList ?

Comment: Need your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946781/how-to-check-app-is-installed-or-not-using-javascript

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with javascript. I have shared a link to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `try` and `catch` block

```
try {
  quantity_count = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString());
  buyNowList(user_id,"UserCart",0,stList.get(position).getCartList1().getId(),stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdSku(),stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdId(),quantity_count,0,qty_status,stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdPrice());
} catch (NumberformatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: is there any way i can check, updated value greater than existing one..for example..if i change from 2 to 5 so 5 is bigger vice versa

Comment: in your aftertextchange save this quantity_count to another variable and than compare

Comment: then how will you compare ??

Comment: if (a>b) , if (a<b)  after you converted two numbers in int

Comment: if(!viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        quantity_count= Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString());
                        // 
                    }

                    int tempqty=quantity_count;

                    if(what to compare)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

Comment: please go here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java&ved=2ahUKEwjD9LekyeXhAhUHsaQKHQokDRUQjjgwC3oECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0yXaSSGw6an3xyVGR-a_2X&cshid=1556000428770

Comment: Bro i know comparision, only issue as per your suggestion it will give same value for both the variables .am i right

Comment: Dude , keep 2 variables at all . One to hold the previous value , and the other to hold the new value and than compare both .

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    try {
        quantity_count = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edt_product_qty.getText().toString()); 
        buyNowList(user_id, "UserCart", 0, stList.get(position).getCartList1().getId(), stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdSku(), stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdId(), quantity_count, 0, qty_status, stList.get(position).getCartList1().getProdPrice());    
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // maybe show some information to user in case of exception
    }
}
```