# How to check app is installed or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-play

I am using javascript to check if app is installed or not, if my app installed i want to open my app or else it will redirect to play store account. the issue is that it is redirecting to play store even i already have app installed

This is my .html file where i am checking for app

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                // Deep link to your app goes here
                document.getElementById("l").src = "intent://sdf/SplashScreen#Intent;scheme=vsd;package=com.sdf.android.ff;end";

                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Link to the App Store should go here -- only fires if deep link fails                
                    window.location = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sdf.android.dffd";
                }, 500);
            };
        </script>
        <iframe id="l" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if that ever onload fired - perhaps set the onload before setting the source, but I still think it's a lost cause

Comment: @JaromandaX please check edited question

Comment: so now you've removed the onload altogether - what stops the timeout from firing? nothing, it will always fire now, guaranteed

Comment: right now issue is that, it is loading play store even the app installed or not

Comment: yes, why wouldn't it?

Comment: but i want to open app if it is installed,,can you help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196998/5156075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It solved by this way

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>


var fallbackToStore = function() {
  window.location.replace('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packgename');
};
var openApp = function() {
  window.location.replace('intent://app/SplashScreen#Intent;scheme=app_;package=com.sdf.android.dsds;end');
};
var triggerAppOpen = function() {
  openApp();
  setTimeout(fallbackToStore, 700);
};

triggerAppOpen();

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the timeout is still executed and the apple store is still opened even after the app is launched. how did you manage this?

Comment: @eugeniobac I think this solution only works for android- it wont work on ios(since you mentioned apple store). Apple broke this to implement universal links.