# Change Spinner entries after EditText changes

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner, populate

I want to change my Spinner entries after changing my EditText:
I have 4 EditText:

```
- edit1
- edit2
- edit3
- edit4
```

I have 2 arrays of spinner entries:

```
- spinner1
- spinner2
```

The rules:
If I write in edit1 and edit2 i get the spinner1;
If I write in edit3 and edit4 i have the spinner2;
If I write in edit1, edit2, edit3 and endit4 i have the spinner1.

I can't have only 1 EditText completed, its the 2 first, the 2 lasts, or the 4 EditText.

My spinners are in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="dureeRemboursement">
    <item>- Choisir -</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>19</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
    <item>25</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="dureeRemboursementcc">
    <item>- Choisir -</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</string-array>
```

I tried 2 ways to populate my spinner:

```
editCapitauxRestants.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursementcc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursement, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            if (editMensualitesTotales.getText().length() > 0 && editCapitauxRestants.getText().length() > 0) {
                spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter1);
            } else {
                spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter0);
            }
        }
    }
});


spinnerDureeRemboursement.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursementcc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursement, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        if (editMensualitesTotales.getText().length() > 0 && editCapitauxRestants.getText().length() > 0) {
            spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

The first don't work besause, the focus still in my EditText when I click on my spinner, and the second too because when I click on the Spinner it bug: i can't scroll the spinner.

xml:

```
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerDureeRemboursement"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dureeRemboursement"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:entries="@array/dureeRemboursementcc"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
```

I tryed with entries in xml and without to see if the bug came from it, but still don't work.

I think there is 2 solutions:
- Quit focus when the user is scrolling;
- Do en focus on my spinner.

---

EDIT:

### I'm in my fragment:

onTextChanged:

```
public class DemandeGratuite extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //placer ici le code pour connaitre la densite et la resolution de lecran
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demande_gratuite, container, false);
...


        /*

        editCapitauxRestants.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursementcc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursement, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    if (editMensualitesTotales.getText().length() > 0 && editCapitauxRestants.getText().length() > 0) {
                        spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    } else {
                        spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        spinnerDureeRemboursement.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursementcc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursement, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                if (editMensualitesTotales.getText().length() > 0 && editCapitauxRestants.getText().length() > 0) {
                    spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter1);
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

        */
...

        return view;
    }

    //Apres creation de la vue ont va creer les evenements
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    }


    public void onTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursementcc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursement, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        int mensualitesTotales = editMensualitesTotales.getText().toString().length();
        int capitauxRestants = editCapitauxRestants.getText().toString().length();
        if (mensualitesTotales > 0 && capitauxRestants > 0)
            spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter1);
        else {
            spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### ANSWER

```
    Spinner spinnerDureeRemboursement;

    EditText editMensualitesTotales, editCapitauxRestants, editMensualitesTotalescc, editCapitauxRestantscc;

    String stringMensualitesTotales, stringCapitauxRestants, stringMensualitesTotalescc, stringCapitauxRestantscc;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //placer ici le code pour connaitre la densite et la resolution de lecran
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demande_gratuite, container, false);

        spinnerDureeRemboursement = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDureeRemboursement);


        editMensualitesTotales = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editMensualitesTotales);
        editCapitauxRestants = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editCapitauxRestants);
        editMensualitesTotalescc = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editMensualitesTotalescc);
        editCapitauxRestantscc = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editCapitauxRestantscc);


        stringMensualitesTotales = editMensualitesTotales.getText().toString();
        stringCapitauxRestants = editCapitauxRestants.getText().toString();
        stringMensualitesTotalescc = editMensualitesTotalescc.getText().toString();
        stringCapitauxRestantscc = editCapitauxRestantscc.getText().toString();

        editCapitauxRestants.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursementcc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.dureeRemboursement, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                if (editMensualitesTotales.getText().length() > 0 && editCapitauxRestants.getText().length() > 0) {
                    spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter1);
                } else {
                    spinnerDureeRemboursement.setAdapter(adapter0);
                }
                //stringMensualitesTotales = s.toString();
                //setupSpinner(stringMensualitesTotales, stringCapitauxRestants, stringMensualitesTotalescc, stringCapitauxRestantscc);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a `TextWatcher` for the `EditTexts`?Get the current length of the `EditText` entry in the textwatcher and use it so set adapters for the `Spinner` Also i think it would be far simpler if the two spinners are on a different screen since they are dependant on the entries of the `EditTexts`.

Comment: @akash93 hi I prefer do on only one screen, i looked on TextWatcher, what mean "afterTextChanged", it's when the focus get out, or when the user is scrolling ? Because my problem is when i'm writing in the edittext and click on the spinner, the focus still in the edtittext.

Comment: You dont need to worry about focus. Save the current contents of the `EditTexts` in some global variables and use those variables for setting up your Spinner.I can post the code skeletion if you wish.  Also you might want to look at  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6003815/3772041) for `TextWatcher` methods

Comment: No you've got it all wrong!I guess I did not convey properly. Refer my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private String editString1,editString2,editString3,editString4;
    public void onCreate(){
    //Initialise views
    edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            editString1 = s.toString();   setupSpinner(editString1,editString2,editString3,editString4)
        })
       //DO the same for other edit texts and save them to appropriate Strings
    }

   public void setupSpinner(String first,String second,String third,String four){
       //Check the strings and set up your spinners appropriately
    }
```

Comment: I have not written the entire code. Hope this explains it

Comment: What are the strings editString1,editString2,editString3,editString4 ? And i have to do an addTextChangedListener to the fourth edittext thats it ? In setupSpinner i put a setAdapter ?

Comment: Error on new TextWatcher(): "Class 'Anonymous class derived from TextWatcher' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int)' in 'TextWatcher"

Comment: The strings are the contents of the EditTexts.. You have to add textchangedlistener to all editTexts. I just wrote the methods that you need to override. `setupSpinner` would be where you have your validation for the strings and set the adapter appropriately