# Updating EditText Value in TextChangedListener Causes Crash

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to limit the edit text value to be less than or equal to 130. In the onCreate method, I did the following:

```
final EditText expectedYears = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lifespan);
expectedYears.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
      }
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count){
          if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString())>130){
                expectedYears.setText(String.valueOf(130));
          }

      }
});
```

I am not really sure why the app crashes after this. By testing, I figured out that the `expectedYears.setText` line is causing this. I feel like once I set the text, the onTextChanged function gets called again. How can I fix this?

Stack Trace

```
 at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:113)
 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5209
 at net.msolonko.motivation_app.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:49) 
 at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:9364)
 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5397)
 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5250)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476848/android-textwatcher-aftertextchanged-vs-textwatcher-ontextchanged), you should not change the text of the EditText being watched in `onTextChanged()`. My guess is that it results in an infinite recursion loop.

Instead, try putting your logic setting the text in `afterTextChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

setText() method requires string type argument, make sure that you are passing string type argument,can use type casting