# Perform action on EditText enter pressed in android while retaining the enter icon on keyboard?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, android-edittext

I want to perform an action when enter is pressed in android editText. I have tried various ways of using `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`, which works, but the problem is, it shows a tick icon, which I don't want. I want it to look like the default enter button on the keyboard.

How do I handle enter pressed event while retaining the "Enter" shape? Is there something like `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_ENTER` to get my job done?

My approach (which shows tick icon):

```
editorEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if( (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            Toast.makeText(EditorActivity.this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

I want it to look like "Enter" shape because I am making a text editor. I am trying to shift to another `EditText` on the "Enter" button is pressed and don't want it to look like a "Tick" button. That's why I don't want the tick symbol.

Comment: Did you try the updated answer? Please let me know if that helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just changing the `inputType` of your `EditText` in your layout should do the trick to have an "Enter" like button in your soft keyboard in Android.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Please note that I have used `textMultiLine` as the `inputType` of the `EditText`.

You can take some action on pressing the "Enter" button in your `EditText` like the following.

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (before == 0 && count == 1 && s.charAt(start) == '\n') {
            String text = edittext.getText().replace(start, start + 1, "").toString(); // Removes the enter
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Hope that completes the answer.

Comment: The thing is, i don't only want to change the keyboard to show enter, i want to listen for it too, this approach does make it look like enter but how i do listen for the enter press using this approach ?

Comment: Can you please check the updated answer? Thanks. :)

Comment: i tried it, but the onKey doesn't get called . nothing happens ,

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you please try with that again? And again, please try to put the debug logs to check if the function `setOnKeyListener` was called or not. Then you modify the conditions for the desired actions to be performed.

Comment: i have already checked it. The onKey() isn't called somehow . 
if you could suggest something with EditorActionListener it would be more appreciative since official doc mention that some keyboards may lead to onKey() not being called !

Comment: Updated the code and tested by myself. This should work now. :)

Comment: it works . can you explain why did you set `before == 0 && count == 1` ?

Comment: Great to know that works. I want to share two links with you which might help you to understand. Here you go with the [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003815/3145960) and [Link 2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher). Please print out those values as well for better understanding.