# How to disable button in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

Tags: disable, material-dialog

How can I disable button in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder?
I want to make similar functionality like in this screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhjyz.png)

I wrote the following code (dialog contains EditText where user should input his favorite food name).

```
final MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogEnterDishName = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context);
        //...
        final EditText editTextEnterDishName = new EditText(context);
        dialogEnterDishName.setView(editTextEnterDishName);

        dialogEnterDishName.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_enter_dish_name_positive_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (!editTextEnterDishName.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    //...
                else {
                    //TODO Make posititve button disabled until the user enters any character
                }
            }
        });
        //...
        dialogEnterDishName.show();
    }
```

I already knew, that class AlertDialog (MaterialAlertDialogBuilder extends AlertDialog.Builder) have a method  `public Button getButton(int whichButton)`, but I can't use it in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.

Please, help!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are calling getButton() function after you inflate your AlertDialog (through `.show()` call). If you are doing it other way around there is no button to get.

In order to enable button back you can use TextWatcher. More details here: [Android TextWatcher.afterTextChanged vs TextWatcher.onTextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476848/android-textwatcher-aftertextchanged-vs-textwatcher-ontextchanged)

```
val customLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_alert_dialog, null, false)
val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Provide name")
            .setView(customLayout)
            .setNeutralButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
            .setPositiveButton("Confirm") { _, _ -> }
            .create()
        
dialog.show()
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).isEnabled = false
```